# Remove Datepicker underline does not works

Tags: .net, maui

I have a custom DatePicker

```
 public class BorderlessDatePicker : DatePicker
 {
       public static readonly BindableProperty EnterTextProperty = 
          BindableProperty.Create(propertyName: "Placeholder", returnType: 
             typeof(string), declaringType: typeof(BorderlessDatePicker), defaultValue: 
                                                                       default(string));
  public string Placeholder { get; set; }
}
```

in XAML I have a Frame with a BorderlessDatePicker, when I select a date the result is:

[image]

I need to remove the underline and set text color to black

If I define a mapper with

#if ANDROID

```
            //handler.PlatformView.Background = null;

            //handler.PlatformView.LayoutParameters is null
            //var layoutParams = new Android.Views.ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(handler.PlatformView.LayoutParameters);
            //layoutParams.SetMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
            //handler.PlatformView.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;
            //handler.PlatformView.SetPadding(70, 0, 0, 0);
            

            handler.PlatformView.BackgroundTintList = Android.Content.Res.ColorStateList.ValueOf(Android.Graphics.Color.Orange);

            BorderlessDatePicker? borderlessDatePicker = view as BorderlessDatePicker;
            if (borderlessDatePicker!=null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(borderlessDatePicker.Placeholder))
            {
                handler.PlatformView.Text = borderlessDatePicker.Placeholder;
            }

            handler.PlatformView.TextChanged += (sender, arg) => {
                var selectedDate = arg?.Text?.ToString();
                if (selectedDate == borderlessDatePicker?.Placeholder)
                {
                    handler.PlatformView.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
                }
            };
```

#endif

and if I select a data the result is

[image]

[image]

I saw the following posts

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1071864/how-to-remove-maui-date-picker-underline
- [Underline datepicker unfocused Net Maui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75668466/underline-datepicker-unfocused-net-maui)

Comment: I don't see what the problem is here. Does it work whenever there is no value set and you see the placeholder? Or the other way around?

Comment: I missed the value from TextColor which was using a binding for a color (white and Grey), just defined as black and worked! Thank you

Comment: You can change color the same as background color.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to remove the underline and set text color to black.

Since you need to set the background color of the [DatePicker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/datepicker?view=net-maui-8.0) to `Orange`, you can also use `handler.PlatformView.SetBackgroundColor` which will **override** and **remove** the underline of [DatePicker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/datepicker?view=net-maui-8.0). For the `TextColor`, as you said, you can change it to black via binding.

Here's the code below for your reference:

```
      Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.DatePickerHandler.Mapper.
AppendToMapping("DatePickerHandler", (handler, view) =>
{
     if (view is BorderlessDatePicker)
     {

#if ANDROID
             
            handler.PlatformView.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Orange);
         
           //Omitted for brevity      
 
#endif
            }
});
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: I used handler.PlatformView.BackgroundTintList = Android.Content.Res.ColorStateList.ValueOf(Android.Graphics.Color.Orange);

Comment: @saramgsilva Yes, that also works, you may need to set the BackgroundColor="Orange" for the Frame.